# NIfi error: OPCUA processor. The server has stopped and cannot process any requests

Tags: java, apache-nifi, opc-ua

I have imported a new OPCUA bundle in Nifi. [Here](https://docs.linksmart.eu/display/NIFI/Nifi+OPC+UA+Bundle+-+Build+and+Deploy)

And this processor reads well for more than a day, but then I get this error:

```
2019-06-04 15:09:17,727 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] d.f.fit.processors.opcua.GetOPCData GetOPCData[id=1e5f35cf-3df7-1e7d-1521-5c8fe9fbd8f6] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_ServerHalted, message=The server has stopped and cannot process any requests.: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_ServerHalted, message=The server has stopped and cannot process any requests.
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_ServerHalted, message=The server has stopped and cannot process any requests.
        at de.fraunhofer.fit.opcua.StandardOPCUAService.getValue(StandardOPCUAService.java:388)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor272.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at de.fraunhofer.fit.processors.opcua.GetOPCData.onTrigger(GetOPCData.java:239)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I restart StandardOPCUAService using Nifi, I can receive the data again. How can I solve this issue? How can I restart the service automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error within the code is something you'll have to address with the authors of that bundle; it's not part of the community-managed Apache NiFi core.

You can automate restarting a processor by using the [NiFi REST API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html). You can use the Developer Tools of your browser to "record" the actions you would take using the UI and see the network calls that change the state of the processor object. Then use a `cron` or other timed scripted approach to invoke this action (you can even put it in an `InvokeHTTP` processor on the NiFi canvas if desired).